# Pivot Table field with custom formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, pivot

I want to make a pivot table with custom field which substract the other column in the pivot.

Here is the sample: [google sheet file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EaxJJjOCCDogMGiYE96ZKqVBKUWDRQ_-zuGSwX_vdVk/edit?usp=sharing)
[image]

"Calculated Field" features wont works, because what I want to formulated are both from the same data column. For example difference or gap of "EVENT_COUNT" from "Open - Loaded".

[image]

Anyone can tell me how to do it?

Either Google sheet and/or excel will be OK.

Comment: It's a `Calculated Item` you need, not a `Calculated Field`.

Comment: i cant use it also, when i use Excel it said "This PivotTable report is grouped. You cannot add calculated item to a grouped field......". I tried to press "Ungroup" button, but it did nothing and the warning still the same.

Comment: AH, i just realized that I put cursor on wrong part, the grouped part is the DATE. I can do it now. Thank you sir

Comment: Did the MS Excel option work for you? I tried in Google Spreadsheet, however, only the **Calculated Field** option is available. This may not be ideal on your end, but do you think [this sample workaround by adding an additional data](https://imgur.com/a/CSQzNWm) using Google Sheet for you?

Comment: Yes, it did. In Excel I was able to use "Calculated Item" after ungrouping the pivot table.